# CSS layout 2 columns in one div with text flowing over into other column

Tags: css

In microsoft word you can make two columns in a document and when you reach the bottom of one column it automatically continues into the top of the other column beside it.
I was wondering if this behaviour is also possible in css?

When I google and search it I find plenty of making a two column webpage layout, but that is not what I want. 
I want the textflow to continue automatically int othe other column.

so that if you have this:

```
<div class="twocolumns">lorem ipsum dolor est.........</div>
```

that you get

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,        ea commodo consequat.
consectetur adipisicing elit,      Duis aute irure dolor 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt   in reprehenderit in voluptate
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  velit esse cillum dolore
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis      eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
nostrud exercitation ullamco 
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
```

Is this even possible with css alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can absolutely do it with CSS3.  Unfortunately I'm not sure how well IE handles this, but a shim or something might help with that.

HTML

```
<div class="twocolumns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu mauris nec nisi tristique condimentum vitae sed orci. Vestibulum luctus hendrerit sem, ut sodales nibh rhoncus a. Mauris a diam mollis ante auctor aliquam. Sed cursus interdum nisl at condimentum. Cras gravida nulla sit amet nisi fringilla bibendum. Suspendisse blandit scelerisque arcu euismod facilisis. Sed ultrices tincidunt commodo. Phasellus sed justo libero. Donec venenatis sapien eu arcu feugiat vulputate. Praesent tortor mauris, tincidunt non venenatis sit amet, ultricies ac lacus. Praesent fermentum pharetra posuere. Quisque eget blandit lacus. Suspendisse eget diam justo. Donec eu urna nec metus consequat pellentesque id nec leo. Nam sodales sapien id tellus rhoncus pellentesque. Ut fringilla imperdiet rhoncus.</div>
```

CSS

```
.twocolumns {
 padding:10px;
  width:80%;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rAnmw/)

Comment: Ha! I love it! thank you for this. I knew it had to be there somewhere, it is just underused.
I already solved it with a jquery column plugin for backwards compatiblity, but this is going into my favorites folder for when css3 becomes mainstream.
thank you so much!